# argparse: Flags from a list

Tags: python, argparse

I have a method in python to parse all the api request needed for my CI library.

Actually whole configuration of this method is stored in a yaml file.

Example:

```
ci:
  sonar:
    name: "python_module.ci.sonar_api"
  env:
    name: "Sonar"
    required:
      AUTH_TOKEN: ["--token", "--t"]
      HOST_URL: ["--url", "--host", "--U"]
    optioal:
      TAGS: ["--tags", "--T"]
      ...
...
```

I use this method also with pythons scripts to generate reports or to be called by jenkins, the examples will be relative with one of these scripts

I have this piece of code to build the argparse (The `args_dict` param is the append of required and optional values, and the `project_name` is any string) :

```
def parse(project_name, args_dict):
    parse_args = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Request to the '+project_name+' api service.'
    )
    for _key in args_dict:
        parse_args.add_argument(
            str(', '.join(args_dict[_key])), action="store", dest=_key,
            help=project_name+" "+_key+" ENV::"+project_name.upper()+"_"+_key,
            default=os.environ.get(project_name.upper()+"_"+_key, None)
        )
    return parse_args
```

And the result of the execution of any of these script is:

```
./sonar_report  -h
sonar_report | 2020-10-31 20:34:18.194862 |  START    | Starting process
usage: sonar_report [-h] [--token, --t AUTH_TOKEN] [--url, --host, --U HOST_URL] [--tags, --T
TAGS]

Request to the Sonar api service.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --token, --t AUTH_TOKEN
                        Sonar AUTH_TOKEN ENV::SONAR_AUTH_TOKEN
  --url, --host, --U HOST_URL
                        Sonar HOST_URL ENV::SONAR_HOST_URL
  --tags, --T TAGS       Sonar TAGS ENV::SONAR_TAGS
```

If I execute this script with the first defined flag it works, but the problem is when I use another flag for any param:

```
usage: sonar_report [-h] [--token, --t AUTH_TOKEN] [--url, --host, --U HOST_URL] [--tags, --T
TAGS]
sonar_report: error: unrecognized arguments: --T test
```

Anyone know how to pass the flags as a list?

**Edit:**

I exclude the error ignoring the unknowns params and print the values of params:

```
def validate(argument_parser, args_dict, ignore_unknowns=None):
    try:
        if ignore_unknowns is None:
            params = vars(argument_parser.parse_args())
        else:
            _params, _unknowns = argument_parser.parse_known_args()
            params = vars(_params)
    except Exception:
        print(f"###ERROR## Trying to parse dictionary's arguments: " +
              f"{str(Exception)}")
        argument_parser.print_help()
        print()
        return None
    print(_params)
    print(_unknowns)
    .........
```

The result is:

```
Namespace(AUTH_TOKEN='***************************',
HOST_URL='***************************', TAGS=None)
['--T', 'test']
```

The the main is something like:

```
 params: project_name, env, required_args=None, ignore_unknowns=True
 return: (validate(parse(project_name, env), required_args, ignore_unknowns))
```

Comment: The `add_argument` should get arguments like `('-T', '--tags', dest=..., help=..., etc)'.  That is, each flag should be a separate string.  I think you are using `('--tags, --T', dest=...)`.  Note that I used "-T", a single dash with the short flag; that's more consistent with `argparse` and POSIX usage.  But the key is each flag is separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a simple dictionary:

```
In [197]: dd = {'foo':['-f', '--foo']}
In [198]: key='foo'


In [206]: import argparse
In [207]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
```

Using your `str/join` to define the argument.  I'm letting `argparse` set the `dest` to make the action clearer:

```
In [208]: parser.add_argument(str(', '.join(dd[key])), help=f'help for {key}')
Out[208]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['-f, --foo'], dest='f, __foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help='help for foo', metavar=None)
In [209]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-f, --foo F, __FOO]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help          show this help message and exit
  -f, --foo F, __FOO  help for foo
In [210]: parser.parse_args([])
Out[210]: Namespace(**{'f, __foo': None})
```

Note that the flag it expects is '-f, --foo', the combination, not the two strings separately.

If I use `**dd[key]` instead, the list of strings is unpacked:

```
In [211]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [212]: parser.add_argument(*dd[key], help=f'help for {key}')
Out[212]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['-f', '--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help='help for foo', metavar=None)
In [213]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-f FOO]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -f FOO, --foo FOO  help for foo
In [214]: parser.parse_args([])
Out[214]: Namespace(foo=None)
In [215]: parser.parse_args(['--foo','foobar'])
Out[215]: Namespace(foo='foobar')
```

Now the dest is `foo`, and both '-f' and '--foo' work.

`add_argument` returns an Action object.  Usually this return is ignored, but in this interactive session it is displayed, giving us a clearer picture of what's happening.

Comment: Yes, that works. Also, I’ve changed the short params with only one dash. Thanks !